# permission issue between hive and bigsql

Tags: hive, bigsql

I am using BigInsights version 3.0. I have created a table in bigsql and inserting into that table from hive. But the process is failing at the end when trying to move the file `Failed with exception Unable to move sourcehdfs://hostname.devdata.company.com:9000/tmp/hive-user1/hive_2015-10-12_09-18-56_797_3643029992887919337-1/-ext-10000 to destination /biginsights/hive/warehouse/db_name.db/table_name`
When I check the permission in HDFS for directory `/tmp/hive-user1` I found its having read-write-execute permission for user only i.e. for user1 only in this case; but the directory `/biginsights/hive/warehouse/db_name.db/table_name` is owned by `bigsql` user so it is failing. Is there anyway to set the read permission for all in HDFS for directory `/tmp/hive-user1` by default; so that the process doesn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

You created a "managed table" because you didn't specify the "EXTERNAL" keyword when you created your table. It is best to use the BigSQL LOAD statement to securly move data into your table.